# PIL: How to reopen an image after verifying?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I need open an image, verify the image, then reopen it (see last sentence of below quote from PIL docs)

> im.verify()
>
> Attempts to determine if the file is broken, without actually decoding
>   the image data. If this method finds any problems, it raises suitable
>   exceptions. This method only works on a newly opened image; if the
>   image has already been loaded, the result is undefined. Also, if you
>   need to load the image after using this method, you must reopen the
>   image file.

This is what I have in my code, where `picture` is a django InMemoryUploadedFile object:

```
img = Image.open(picture)
img.verify()
img = Image.open(picture)
```

The first two lines work fine, but I get the following error for the third line (where I'm attempting to "reopen" the image):

`IOError: cannot identify image file`

What is the proper way to reopen the image file, as the docs suggest?

Comment: how does django factor into this?  what is `picture`?

Comment: @Eevee Thanks for catching that, I've removed the django tag. `picture` is an InMemoryUploadedFile that is an image file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is no different than doing

```
f = open('x.png')
Image.open(f)
Image.open(f)
```

The code above does not work because PIL advances in the file while reading its first few bytes to (attempt to) identify its format. Trying to use a second `Image.open` in this situation will fail as noted because now the current position in the file is past its image's header. To confirm this, you can verify what `f.tell()` returns. To solve this issue you have to go back to the start of the file either by doing `f.seek(0)` between the two calls to `Image.open`, or closing and reopening the file.

Comment: Awesome, I did not know that! Could you please provide a simple example of how to open, verify, close/seek, then reopen?

Comment: @sgarza62 I'm not sure I follow but you just have to do exactly that. `f = open('x.png'); img = Image.open(f); img.verify(); f.seek(0); img = Image.open(f)`. Instead of `f.seek(0)` you could do `f.close(); f = open('x.png')`. I guess I missed something, because this can't get more trivial.

Comment: That's what I thought. I tried that, and I'm getting an error `coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, InMemoryUploadedFile found` at the first line (`f=open(original)`)...I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.

Comment: That is just a different kind of file object you have. Quickly searching for anything related to it, I got this diagram at http://docs.nullpobug.com/django/trunk/django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile-class.html indicating there is a `seek` method for this object. You might want to consider reading some Django (and possibly Python in general) tutorial if this is not clear yet.

Comment: Thanks for that. Here's what worked, referencing my original example (just in case anyone else encounters the same problem with InMemoryUploadedFile objects): `img=Image.open(picture) ; img.verify() ; picture.seek(0) ; img=Image.open(picture)` In other words, no need for the first line.

Comment: You don't need the first line, i.e. `f = open('x.png')`, because you are already receiving an opened file object. What you are naming as `picture`, is named as `f` in the example. The example wouldn't require the first line if the object `f` was available beforehand, which is your case.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a `del img` between the `verify` and second `open`.